# QR decomposition proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A\in\mathbb{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $m>n$ and $rank(A)=n$ and take the decomposition $A=QR$ with $Q\in\mathbb{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ a orthogonal matrix and $R\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ a upper triangular matrix with diagonal elements positive. Assume that $R^*(A)$ is a column space of $A$ and $N^*(A)$ is a null space of $A$ * is just a notation.
Show that

i)$R^*(A)=R^*(Q)$

ii)$N^*(A^t)=N^*(Q^t)$

iii)$R^*(A^t)=R^*(Q^t)=\mathbb{R}^n$

iv)$N^*(A)=N^*(Q)=0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$

Can anyone give me help?

Comment: What is a nonsquare orthogonal matrix?  Another thing I don't get in your questions -- if $^*$ doesn't mean anything, why do you keep adding it to your questions?

Comment: @Bye_World I think it must be square, $m\times n$ is just a notation.

Comment: Well if $Q$ *is* $m\times n$, then orthogonal *could* mean $Q^TQ=I$ **or** it could mean $QQ^T=I$ -- but if $m\ne n$, then these are not equivalent statements so you'd need to tell us which one this problem assumes.

Comment: @Bye_World The statement does not say anything, but I'm assuming $m=n$

Comment: This would be the 'thin' QR factorisation. In general, $m \ge n$.

Comment: @askazy Can you immediately tell that $\operatorname{col}(QR) \subseteq \operatorname{col}(Q)$?  If not, prove it.  Can you see that if $R$ is an upper triangular matrix with all nonzero elements on its diagonal (because they're positive) then it $x \mapsto Rx$ is bijective?  If not, prove it.  Then can you see that if $R$ represents a bijective mapping, then $\dim(\operatorname{col}(QR)) = \dim(\operatorname{col}(Q))$?  If not, prove it.  Then can you see that if $\operatorname{col}(QR) \subseteq \operatorname{col}(Q)$ and $\dim(\operatorname{col}(QR)) = \dim(\operatorname{col}(Q))$, then ...

Comment: $\operatorname{col}(QR) = \operatorname{col}(Q)$?  If not, then prove it.

Comment: @Bye_World Sorry, it is the translator that the times of these meaningless phrases. I mean I need to prove it, I can not take direct.

Comment: I'm all out of answers today.  Maybe [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520417/rank-and-the-column-space-of-matrix-product) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a matrix with full column rank meaning that the columns are linearly independent. we also have $$A = QR, Q^\top Q= I_n, R \text{ upper triangular.}  $$

we will try to prove that column space $C(A), C(Q)$ of $A$ and $Q$  are the same.  i wil do the case $n = 3.$ the general case should be similar and you can do that. we will write $A = QR$  as $$[a_1, a_2, a_3] = [q_1, q_2, q_3]R $$ this means each of the columns of $A$ are a linear combinations of the columns of $Q$. in particuls $a_3 = r_{13}q_1 + r_{23}q_2 + r_{33}q_3.$ that implies $C(A) \subset C(Q).$

to establish $C(Q) \subset C(A),$ we can use the fact that $R$ is invertible and write $A = QR$ as $A R^{-1} = Q$  which implies the columns of $Q$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A.$ and we are done.

next i will do part(iv). we will show that null spaces and $A$ and $R$ are the same.
 suppose $x \in \ker(A).$  then $Ax = 0 \to QRx =0 \to Q^\top Q R x = 0\to Rx = 0.$ this shows $\ker A \subset \ker R.$  the other way is much easier and i will let you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever $A=BF$, where $F$ is an invertible matrix, we have $R^*(A)=R^*(B)$ (using your notation).

Indeed, if $v\in R^*(A)$, we have $v=Ax$ for some $x$, so $v=(BF)x=B(Fx)\in R^*(B)$. The converse inclusion follows from $B=AF^{-1}$.

Under the same hypotheses, we have $A^t=F^tB^t$; if $w\in N^*(B)$, then $A^tw=F^tB^tw=0$, so $w\in N^*(A^t)$. The converse inclusion follows from the fact that $B^t=(F^{-1})^tA^t$.

In case $A=FB$, with invertible $F$, it's true that $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, because multiplication by $F$ induces a (bijective) linear map from the column space of $B$ to the column space of $A$. Thus
$$
n=\operatorname{rank}Q^t=\operatorname{rank}A^t
$$
The rank-nullity theorem says that both $Q^t$ and $A^t$ have zero null space.

As you see, it's not really relevant that $Q$ has orthogonal columns.